# There exists $c \in [0,1]$ for which $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) = \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2)$

Tags: calculus

T/F: There exists $c \in [0,1]$ for which $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) = \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2)$

I know the answer it true, and I already saw the proof. What I don't get is this:

$\sin$ is monotonically increasing in $[0, 1]$, so from the monotonocity of integrals:

$$\sin(x^3) \leq \sin(x^2) \quad \forall x \in [0, 1]$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) \leq \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^2) \quad \forall x \in [0, 1]$$
$$L = \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) \leq \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2) + \int_{c}^{1}\sin(x^2) = R \quad \forall x \in [0, 1]$$

So if there exists such $c$, it means that:

case 1: $L < R \implies \int_{c}^{1}\sin(x^2) < 0 \quad$  which is false.
case 2: $L = R \implies \int_{c}^{1}\sin(x^2) = 0 \implies c = 1 \implies \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) = \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^2) \quad$ which is again, false

So what's going on?

Comment: the conclusion of the first case is false

Comment: Numerically, $0.9 < c < 0.91$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\int_0^1\sin(x^3)\,dx$ and consider
$$
f(t)=\int_0^t \sin(x^2)\,dx
$$
Then $f(0)\le L\le f(1)$ and by the intermediate value theorem $L=f(c)$ for some $c\in[0,1]$.

About your doubts. It doesn't make sense to say
$$
\int_0^1\sin(x^3)\,dx\le\int_0^1\sin(x^2)\,dx
\qquad \text{for all $x\in[0,1]$}
$$
as the integrals *don't depend* on $x$.

Then, indeed,
$$
L\le\int_0^c\sin(x^2)\,dx+\int_c^1\sin(x^2)\,dx
$$
just says that
$$
\int_c^1\sin(x^2)\,dx\ge0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
\int_0^1 \sin x^3 \le \int_0^c \sin x^2 + \int_c^1 \sin x^2
$$

Let

$$
\int_0^1 \sin x^3 = \int_0^c \sin x^2
$$

Then

$$
\int_0^1 \sin x^3 - \int_0^c \sin x^2 \le \int_0^c \sin x^2 - \int_0^c \sin x^2 + \int_c^1 \sin x^2 \\
0 \le \int_c^1 \sin x^2
$$

So your first case seems to be off.

Comment: Oh wow I am so stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are only considering $c\leq1$ and to satisfy that equation surely must be $c>1$

EDIT: ppl... he only asked to point what is he missing not to show any proves... you should all be marked as irrelevant answer -.-

Answer (score 0):

From a purely algebraic point of view,$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) =\frac{1}{6} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+i
   \left(E_{\frac{2}{3}}(-i)-E_{\frac{2}{3}}(i)\right)\right)\approx 0.233845 $$ $$ \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} S\left(c \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)$$ where appear the exponential integral function and the Fresnel integral.

This makes the function $$f(x)= \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2)- \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) $$ canceling only once for $c\approx0.902752$ as Felix Marin already pointed out in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that for some $c\in[0,1]$
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{3}z^{1/3} \frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz = \int_{0}^{c^2} \frac{1}{2}z^{1/2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz $$
holds, that is the same as showing that for some $d\in[0,1]$
$$ C=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{3}z^{1/3} \frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz = f(d)=\int_{0}^{d} \frac{1}{2}z^{1/2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz $$
holds. Since $f$ is a continuous function over $[0,1]$, $C>0$ and $f(0)=0$, it is enough to prove $f(1)>C$, then exploit the mean value property of continuous functions.
 
Let $\alpha=\frac{64}{729}$ and consider that $\frac{1}{2}z^{1/2}-\frac{1}{3}z^{1/3}$ is increasing over $[0,1]$, while $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is decreasing:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(1)-C &=& \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}z^{1/2}-\frac{1}{3}z^{1/3}\right)\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz\\&\geq&-\alpha+\int_{\alpha}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}z^{1/2}-\frac{1}{3}z^{1/3}\right)\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz\\&\geq&-\alpha+\sin(1)\int_{\alpha}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}z^{1/2}-\frac{1}{3}z^{1/3}\right)\,dz\color{red}{>0}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and we are done.

Answer (score -1):

Hint : put $f(t)=\int_0^t \sin(x^2)dx$ to conclude